# Blazor WASM Default Template Publish Size Way Too Large (15mb), Production even larger

Tags: .net, blazor, publish, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

I cannot figure out what is making my Blazor WASM publishes so large. They are supposed to be about2mb according to my research. I have all the build packages, runtimes, configurations, etc and it keeps ending up so large. I'm going to add all the information for the blazor wasm default template not hosted, PWA that generates 15mb.

Launch Profile

```xml
xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121.
-->
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>true</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>false</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>true</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <PublishUrl>bin\Release\net7.0\browser-wasm\publish\</PublishUrl>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <_TargetId>Folder</_TargetId>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>browser-wasm</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <ProjectGuid>2e8e251e-6972-4c32-9091-7cf38c02e7a5</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>service-worker-assets.js</ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>
    <BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>true</BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="7.0.5" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ServiceWorker Include="wwwroot\service-worker.js" PublishedContent="wwwroot\service-worker.published.js" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Webconfig

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".blat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dll" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".blat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Serve subdir">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SPA fallback routing" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/wasm" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/font-woff" enabled="true" />
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/wasm" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/font-woff" enabled="true" />
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[Application Size Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f4M9.png)

[VS Installer packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85nL9.png)

[Network Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9v02.png)

[Publish Folder Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCWQZ.png)

[_framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk3tp.png)

[IIS Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkXZt.png)

Build Output

https://paste.mod.gg/xoaxppweovns/0

Full transfer size about 7.2mb

Comment: @HH About 7.2mb transferred on the default template with gzip.